# Tracking who is using VPN

Tags: vpn

Is it possible for a company to track who logs into work using VPN? How is this information tracked.  I use a RSA token that is installed on my cell phone. I enter a code into the RSA app, then it gives me a new code. Does the VPN software track who uses the service?

Comment: Hi S and welcome to this site. This question has already been partially covered. Please consider reading the other question and clarifying in which way your specific question differs from others.

Comment: If you use a crappy VPN (there are many) they can even decrypt your traffic.

Comment: @SteveDL: As per my understanding this question is the other way around. It is not about an employee within the enterprise network using a VPN to access outside networks, but employee outside of the enterprise network using their corporate VPN access to access company's internal network, and if such access can be linked to an individual (which however should be quite an obvious requirement otherwise the company may have a serious security issue...).

Comment: Right. I saw a few questions discussing the outside user topic already, OP should really use the search function...

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly. Someone along the line they get your username so that they can validate your RSA token. You likely type this in (or did during installation). They log that.

Being network and security software, I suspect the VPN logs all sorts of stuff including your originating IP address, your VPN IP address, summary stats of network traffic, etc...

Answer (score 0):

All enterprise VPN systems I have experience with have logging which will include detail as to who is connecting/disconnecting, the IP address of the client, how much traffic was passed and more.  Logging of this information is configurable... could be all of this, could be none of it.